# How do I reload menuinfo Android?

Tags: android, contextmenu, expandablelistview

I'm using context menu in my expandaple list view, and when add a new child on it, I need to tell the system which child will get the context menu

I tried to use `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, but it doesn't give me the `menuInfo`. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        final EntryDAO dao = EntryDAO.getInstance(this);

        ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info =
                (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

        int type =
                ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);

        final int groupPosition =
                ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);

        final int childPosition =
                ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);

        // Only create a context menu for child items
        if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD && childPosition < listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size() - 1) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the problem was in my implementation of BaseAdapter. Setting a click on child that android was recycling so the long click was not working.